# Can't find folder in file server by using pathname

Tags: file-server

Need help from community here
I can't find needed folder by type in start menu
It got no problem when I try to mapping

Comment: Need help from community here I can't find needed folder by type the filepath in start menu. But it got no problem when I try to mapping

Comment: Are you saying your system could not find the folder after typing at search field in start menu but you could map the folder from network ?

Comment: yes, sir. using same path for both method but got different result. mapping = can access the folder. search field in start menu = failed

Answer (score 0):

A mapped folder from the network may have a totally different folder location/name on the server.

Example: in the network you can have something like: "\fileserver\Research\MainFiles" (what an user or group of users see on the network) but on the actual "fileserver" server that location may be under something like "D:\RSR\MainFiles".